# Condtional readOnly checkbox still editable

Tags: reactjs, formik

I have a table of checkboxes (true/false values), `initialValues` are populated from an api call. Each "facility" has a `Enabled` and `Immutable` value. If `Immutable` is true the `Enabled` checkbox should be checked AND `readOnly`, meaning it can't be unchecked. So if `Immutable` is `false`, the `Enabled` checkbox should be editable.

I'm using the following snippet to render the above scenario

```
<Table.Cell>
  {JSON.stringify(enabled) === "true" &&
  `facilities[${index}].immutable` ===
    "true" ? (
    <Field
      type="checkbox"
      name={`facilities[${index}].enabled`}
      readOnly
    />
  ) : (
    <>
     <Field
       type="checkbox"
       name={`facilities[${index}].enabled`}
     />
    </>
 )}
</Table.Cell>
```

[I have a codesandbox here](https://codesandbox.io/s/logging-table-l2rut). You can see the values updated by checking/unchecking the boxes in the debug state below the table in the sandbox.

It seems like the condition is always false and rendering the non `readOnly` `<Field />`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<Table.Cell>
  {JSON.stringify(enabled) === "true" &&
  `facilities[${index}].immutable` ===
    "true" ? (
    <Field
      type="checkbox"
      name={`facilities[${index}].enabled`}
      // readOnly
      disabled
    />
  ) : (
    <>
     <Field
       type="checkbox"
       name={`facilities[${index}].enabled`}
     />
    </>
 )}
</Table.Cell>
```

Comment: Weird that `readOnly` doesn't work. `disabled` does. Also, The second condition check should also just be `JSON.stringify(immutable)`

Comment: Well, it an implementation choice. That's why it is important to check the lib documentation. Happy it helped. Happy coding!